# How to display variable value from Python in KV file in kivy app

Tags: python, json, variables, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to display variable `archon2_channel` from the function `label_title` as an `MDLabel` text value. I have tried to use `StringProperty(var_name)`, also through the global variables, no luck... appreciated for any ideas and or links that can help to solve it.

I am placing this function in the App class:

Python:

```
class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.standard_increment = STANDARD_INCREMENT
        self.load_all_kv_files(os.path.join(self.directory, "libs", "uix", "kv",))
        self.load_all_kv_files(os.path.join(self.directory, "libs", "uix", "uix_drawer", "kv"))
        self.root_widget = RootWidget()
        self.screen_manager = self.root_widget.ids.screen_manager
        self.nav_drawer = self.root_widget.ids.navigation_drawer
        return self.root_widget

    def label_title(self):
        url_archon2 = "http://weburrl"
        response_archon2 = requests.request("GET", url_archon2, headers=headers, data = "")
        archon2_channel = response_archon2.json()['items']['contentChannel']
        archon2_ticker = response_archon2.json()['items']['messageScheduleName']
        print(archon2_channel)
        print(archon2_ticker)
        return StringProperty(archon2_ticker)

DemoApp().run()
```

KV file:

```
MDLabel
    text: app.archon2_channel
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    padding: 0, "20dp"
    halign: "center"
    theme_text_color: "Primary"
```

Comment: Is the variable in scope of app? are you able to share more code?

Comment: @Goldwave hey, just did thank you!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "display json's value"? Where does this value come from? Which exact variable is this in the code you show here?

Comment: Nice! have you tried this.archon2_channel  response_archon2.json()['items']['contentChannel']? I'm not really familiar with kivy, but i try

Comment: @Code-Apprentice archon2_channel

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry i should specify better, json value basically stored in archon2_channel variable

Comment: @Goldwave im not sure what you recommend to do?

Comment: Your use of kivy properties is not correct, they must be defined at class level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm it actually just happened )) here is what i did, i removed code from function label_title() and put it in a class DemoApp(MDApp) level:

```
class DemoApp(MDApp):
    url_archon2 = "web url"
    r_dev_info_archon2 = requests.request("GET", url_archon2, headers=headers, data="")
    ch_numb_archon2 = r_dev_info_archon2.json()['items']['contentChannel']
```

in KV file:

```
MDLabel
    text: app.ch_numb_archon2
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    padding: 0, "20dp"
    halign: "center"
    theme_text_color: "Primary"
```

Easier than i thought!